# How to add attachments for comments list in sharepoint blog 2010?

Tags: 2010

In sharepoint 2010 blog, we have posts list , comments list. we can add attachments to a post list easily but however while commenting we are not provided with attachment option. Tried many ways but it doesnt seem to work well. Can you guys please give us any solution??!!

Answer (score 1):

The out-of-the-box SP 2010 blog post does not have a field for file attachments. You can insert a file in the rich text field for the blog post, though.

The comments body does not seem to be enhanced rich text enabled. But you could add an enhanced rich text field to the comment list and remove the body field. Then you can insert files into comments, too.